# Use previous yet still valid H-1B visa to enter the U.S. while my current H-1B visa application is in administrative processing

Tags: usa, visa

My previous H1B visa stamp is still valid but I applied for renewal in China recently. Unfortunately my application needs administrative processing, which may take a few weeks.

So I borrowed my passport and promised to return it once the AP is cleared. But I found there is no "cancelled" mark on my previous H1B visa stamp.

So I am wondering whether I can use my previous visa to enter the US. I will get back to China to paste my new visa stamp once it is issued.

I am also wondering what the consequence would be if I was denied entry to the US.

Comment: Did you try asking the embassy about this?